# Find and replace without storing variable

Tags: regex, perl

Is there a way to do this in one line?

```
my $b = &fetch();
$b =~ s/find/replace/g;
&job($b)
```

Comment: `my $b = &fetch(); $b =~ s/find/replace/g; &job($b)`

Comment: Ha! That is one way, but that is not what I meant...

Comment: any reason why you _need_ to use & to call a sub? Are you using Perl v4?

Comment: I am using perl 5.8.8. The above code is a minimal example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, with a `do {}` block:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub fetch { 'please find me' }
sub job   { print @_, "\n"   }

job( do { $_ = fetch(); s/find/replace/g; $_ } );
```

The reason being that in Perl you *cannot* do `fetch() =~ s/find/replace/;`:
`Can't modify non-lvalue subroutine call in substitution (s///) at ...`

Perl 5.14 will introduce the `/r` flag (which makes the regex return the string with substitutions rather than the number of substitutions) and will reduce the above to:

```
job( do { $_ = fetch(); s/find/replace/gr; } );
```

**edited** thanks to FM: can shorten the above to:

```
job( map { s/find/replace/g; $_ } fetch() );
```

And once Perl 5.14 will be out it can be shortened to:

```
job( map { s/find/replace/gr } fetch() );
```

Comment: Upvote for the info on Perl 5.14; this is why I read answers to questions I think I already know, because sometime you still learn even when you DID know! Now if only we could get Ubuntu to deliver something newer than 5.10.1.

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/dist/App-perlbrew/lib/App/perlbrew.pm is easy and painless. You should not really rely on the _system_ Perl for your code, anyway :)

Comment: always localize changes to `$_`

Comment: If you use `map` instead of `do`, you'll localize the change to $_ and won't need to make the initial assignment: `job( map { s/find/replace/g; $_ } fetch() )`.

Answer (score 4):

If you are asking whether you have to go through a scalar variable to do the replace, the answer is yes. This is because the result of the substitution has to be stored somewhere. Also, the substitution does not return the variable used, it returns the number of substitutions made. Therefore, you can't inline it (i.e., &job($b =~ s/find/replace/g) ) in the function call.

Comment: In Java I can send the result of `replaceAll(regex)` directly into the job subroutine. I was hoping it could be done in Perl. I will wait awhile before I give up.

Comment: GeorgeBailey, the Java approach will also require intermediate memory storage of the result, only that it's behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (fetch() . '') {   # append with '' to make sure it is a non-constant value
    s/find/replace/g;
    job($_)
}
```

or use `apply` from one of the List modules:

```
use List::Gen qw/apply/;

job( apply {s/find/replace/g} fetch() );
```